# Gitlab pages URL config

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-pages

default gitlab pages use `http(s)://<namespace>.company.io/<project>` as base url.

Can we config it to `http(s)://<project>.<namespace>.company.io/`?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can't after looking the information about configuring gitlab pages.( https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/pages/ ) it seems that you can't do that configuration of multiple subdomain levels for projects.